# wrap text in an entry widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create an interactive text box in a tkinter GUI, the text box should get the text to wrap to the next line after the length of 30 characters, like it would do using the `wraplength=30` attribute in a label widget. I am trying to get it to work using an Entry widget, this is what I am aiming for (apart from the wraplength attribute needs to be changed to something that works in an Entry widget:
`ent = Entry(root, width=30, wraplength=30)`

I also need to be able to make the Entry widget taller than one line, is there a way i can do that, for example making it vertically fill a frame (similarly to `expand=True` making it horizontally fill a frame).

Thank you!

Comment: Read about [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Entry widgets are single line only, you may want to try Text widget

https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/morewidgets.html#text

Answer (score 1):

The entry widget doesn't support wrapping. If you want to have multiple lines -- even if it's one long line that's wrapped -- you'll need to use either a `Text`, `Label`, or `Message` widget. Only the `Text` widget supports user input, the other two are strictly for display.

As for making the entry widget taller, you can do that with a geometry manager. For example, you can use the `sticky` option of `grid` or the `fill` and `expand` options of `pack`. This will make the widget taller, but the text will still just appear as a single line.